# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /box/main.c - Internal Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am currently working on a project that needs judge0 API.
Firstly, I used it with rapid-api and all run well.

I recently decided to move to a self-hosted with `docker-compose.yml` file. My container runs well, I can make a submission (because I get a token) but when I try to get the detail of my submission, I have an internal error.

Here my request:

```
let url = `http://localhost:2358/submissions/${jsonResponse.token}?base64_encoded=false`;
  const getSolution = await fetch(url, {
method: "GET",
headers: {
// //   "x-rapidapi-host": "judge0-ce.p.rapidapi.com",
// //   "x-rapidapi-key": API_KEY,
"content-type": "application/json",
},
  });
  jsonGetSolution = await getSolution.json();
```

Someone could help me?

I tried to manage this file by switching to `true` the `deprecatedCgroupv1` key

`nano ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json`

Answer (score 1):

Steps i took to resolve the issue in the mac M2 chip system.

1. enabled the deprecatedCgroupv1 to true in the

> vim ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json

2. i was getting following warning msg when i was running docker compose for judge0

> server The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the
> detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was
> requested

To resolve the above issue you need to enable the rosetta in the docker desktop

> go to settings >
> Features in development enable checkbox for Use >
> enable checkbox for Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon

to understand more on the why we need to enable refer the [article](https://collabnix.com/warning-the-requested-images-platform-linux-amd64-does-not-match-the-detected-host-platform-linux-arm64-v8/)